# Mysql return empty matchs in JOIN as null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have these tables

> **cat** (holds main data for categories) id_cat, original name
>   **cat_lang** (holds cat details in different languages)   lang, id_cat,local_name
>   **cat_media** (holds cat media) id_cat, id_media, usage (may have base or big)
>   **media** (holds image information) id_media, name, path

I made a query which returns sub categories of selected category like this.

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from('cat')
         ->join('cat_lang','cat.id_cat = cat_lang.id_cat','left outer')
         ->join('cat_media','cat.id_cat= cat_media.id_cat','left outer')             
         ->join('media','cat_media.id_media=media.id_media','left outer')
         ->where('cat.id_parent',$id_cat) //comes from function             
         ->where('cat_lang.lang',$lang)
$query = $this->db->get();
```

I will filter the big images after then with:

```
  $sub_cats = $query->result_array(); 
  $data['sub_cats']= array();
  foreach($sub_cats as $key => $value)
  {
    if($value['usage'] == 'base' OR $value['usage'] == null)
    $data['sub_cats'][] = $value;
  }
```

`$value['usage'] == null` is where the trouble begins. Problem is in some categories, there is not attached base image and above query does not return this categories because it did not match in `cat.id_cat= cat_media.id_cat` condition.

I want to get in result table:

```
id_cat:1 , ..., id_media = 2, usage=big
id_cat:2 , ..., id_media = null, usage=null
```

So I need them in the result table as null. How can I do that? Stacked here for hours. Thanks for any help..

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen, Thanks for corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I am trying something which is not possible.
Trying to get categories which has image attached, but also asking which are no image attached as well. I make sure that while creating a category I am attaching a default no-preview image now, now query does the job. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left outer join` instead of a simple `join`.

Comment: I used left outer and it workes but one thing is missing: id_cat comes empty rest are ok. What may cause it?

Comment: There are multiple `id_cat`in your query. Make sure you use the `cat.id_cat`.